# How to Launch a browser in background while Excel VBA running a macro in a userForm remains active in foreground

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA program using Excel for Input and Output primarily. It is a financial program to provide tracking of income, expenses (both cash and credit card) that allows for low income persons to keep a current and accurate account of everything as opposed to the bank who can only show what is in the bank without knowledge of checks and other expenses (credit cards) that take a while to get back. I am self taught on Basic, Visual Basic, VBA, Excel etc. The only knowledge I have of Object Oriented Programming is what I was forced to learn with this application. I have now reached the point of a problem I am not even sure if it can be solved as I see it:

Description - When a bill is incurred I post it to the system as Pending. It checks to insure there is money avail to pay it and moves the money into Pend Income then does numerous other steps to document the transaction. At this point, I go to my bank URL via a browser (typically Chrome, but have tried Fire Fox and Edge) and move the money from a reserve list to my spend account so the money is actually ready for payment. Herein, lies the problem. VBA uses a userForm(required to get size and color for weak eyes to see) and asks if a bank update is required. If "YES" then it calls browser to open and access web site URL. For one reason or another, it takes approx. 1 minute or more to open. During that time I have a timer with a progress bar to show seconds passing to confirm actual process in the activity and as a pacifier to keep me from fearing the Blue Screen of Death syndrome ( read that as insuring I didn't put the system in a endless loop somewhere). The problem seems to be that once Windows starts to get the browser it takes focus from Excel and VBA and I can not see the timer(progress Bar) until the site is opened AND then closed. Is it possible to open the browser site in the background, and when open, notify user somehow to go to Windows and use the site? And of course, leave the progress bar on top until browser IS made focal point.

INFO:
OS Win 10
Excel Office365
PC Dell with 1tb HD & 32gb mem

If somebody reminds me how to, I'll attach a workbook with one sheet, one form and one module  and about 6 macros. The timer is a modified version of wellsr.com Progress Bar set to use seconds as progress quantity.

Comment: No. VBA is single-threaded, can only do one thing at a time. You could move the whole process to _.Net_ and program in _C#_ or _VB.NET_. Lots of options to control Excel files this way.

Comment: Starting the browser without activation should be possible by using the API [ShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea) and specifying SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE in the nShowCmd member. But detecting when the page is fully loaded in an arbitrary browser is probably a very difficult task, if not impossible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.